# Update datetime column in sql server using dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, datetime

This is my dynamic SQL query to update the column values.
It does not update the `OccureDateTime` column.

```
set @sql='update AttendenceReg set '+ @ColName+'=''A'''+',
    TotalAbsent='+convert(varchar,@TotalAbsent)+ ',
    OccurDateTime='''+@startDate+'''' +' 
    where UserId='+@userId+' and 
    ContractorName='+''''+@currentcontractorname+''''+' and 
    SiteName='+''''+@sitename+''''+' and 
    '+@ColName+' is null';--+' and(convert(datetime,select max(occurdatetime) from AttendenceReg whereUserId='+@userId+',103)='+'convert(datetime,''''+@prev_dt+'''',103)'+')';
```

But when I change it to the simple SQL query the query is works correctly.

In case I pass 
`OccurDateTime='+@startDate+''+'` it will insert `01/01/1990`  into the`OccurDateTime` column.

Comment: I'm guessing this is not for MySQL?

Comment: no this is for sql server

Comment: Then please take care to format your questions. You tagged it with MySQL which will confuse people and the formatting of the code was hard to read until @MarkSinkinson kindly fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow this way:

```
@sql = '....
<a datetime field> = CAST(''' + CAST(<a datetime variable> AS varchar) + ''' As datetime) ...'
```